# Surface Integration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, gauss-law, vector-fields, calculus

[image]

I've been studying surface integration by myself but I always stuck at the last step.
Consider the above question:
This is my approach:

1. Calculation of the curl of the given field.
2. Calculation of unit vector.
3. Dot product of the unit vector and the curl of the field.
4. Then I projected the Hemisphere surface on the XY plane.

In the last step, there is a Z.

Now, this is where I face trouble.
What should I do with Z? Since the area element in the XY plane is $$ds=dxdy$$ my limits of the integration will be in X and Y.
I thought of replacing the Z with 0(zero) because I am working in XY plane. But then my integrand would diverge.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing in step 4 by projecting onto the XY plane is *parameterizing* your surface in terms of its $x$ and $y$ coordinates. This means the coordinates of any point on the surface can be found by specifying just $x$ and $y$, i.e. $\mathbf r = (x(x,y),y(x,y),z(x,y))$. Obviously $x(x,y) = x$ and $y(x,y) = y$, but to find $z(x,y)$ you have to invert the equation of a sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$. For this you just rearrange to get $z^2 = 1 - x^2 - y^2$ and since you are dealing with the top half of the sphere you take the positive square root to get

$$z(x,y) = \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$$

Now you can replace $z$ in your integral to get an integrand in terms of only $x$ and $y$.